# Best method to scrape info when multiple data needs to be entered

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I want to make a program that scrapes info from the lifesaving society website. https://www.lifesavingsociety.com/find-a-member.aspx

I would be coding this in python btw. Basically, I would want the program to take in a list of lifesaving id's and return info about when each person's certifications are expiring. The problem is, to scrape this data I feel that I would need to have the program individually enter each lifesaver's id # and then scrape the data. This feels like something that would take a long time and I thought maybe there was a better way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Step 1: Get a written permission to do so as requiered by their legal notice.

Comment: This is just for personal use

Comment: You can use multiple threads to scrape multiple ids at once. Check out the `threading` module in python

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.